# GameHelper crashes on onConnectionFailed()

Tags: android, google-play-games

I've got the following crash in `GameHelper.java`:

> [main] java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.resolveConnectionResult(GameHelper.java:752)
>     at
>   com.google.example.games.basegameutils.GameHelper.onConnectionFailed(GameHelper.java:729)

The only reason I think that could happen is if `mActivity == null` at `GameHelper.java:752`:

```java
mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, RC_RESOLVE);
```

`mActivity` gets null on `onStop()`
Is it possible that GameHelper.java has bug and can crash if `onConnectionFailed()` happens after `onStop()` is called?
Thanks.

EDITED:
It happened after update to the latest Play API (rev 15) together with the updated GameHelper.java.

Comment: if you set the `mActivity` to `null` in your `onStop()` method, then yes, this could cause an error if you call `startResolutionForResult()` after that, but what seems more likely to me is that `mConnectionResult==null`, is that possible?

Comment: If mConnectionResult would be null it would crash on a different line.
in my on stop I call GameHelper.onStop() which sets the mActivity to null besides other variables. resolveConnectionResult() does not check those and the app crashes.
It happened after update to the latest Play API (rev 15) together with the updated GameHelper.java.

Comment: This happened to me after I updated to the latest Google Play API too from Feb 24.On the error messages there wasn't any of my code :(

Answer (score 8):

EDIT:

This now has been fixed in latest GameHelper version:
https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/commit/e7b3758c136b5b434f1dfd9ca8c03f75aad70f09

OLD ANSWER:

For me it happens on the start of the app, when Google Play Services asks me to sign in and if I click cancel, this same error happens.

So when leaving from your own activity to sign in activity, it dispatches onStop event, and fails to connect because of the user initiated process, which is resolvable, thus the error happens.

So my quick hack was changing:

```
catch (SendIntentException e)
```

to simply

```
catch (Exception e)
```

So it would also catch Null pointer exception
Of course in this case the signup process might not proceed, so I initate relogin on another action and it seems to work for now.

More thorough hack could be trying to resolve the result on activity start, for that we define pending resolution variable:

```
// Are we expecting the result of a resolution flow?
boolean mExpectingResolution = false;
boolean mPendingResolution = false;
```

Then on the error line we check if activity is not null

```
if(mActivity != null)
    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, RC_RESOLVE);
else
    mPendingResolution = true;
```

And on start we check and try to resolve it:

```
if(mPendingResolution && mConnectionResult != null)
try {
    mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mActivity, RC_RESOLVE);
} catch (SendIntentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This should help until the official resolution from lib supporters :)

Comment: This is reintroduced in commit https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/commit/81ff43c (25.03.2014 by Wolff)

Answer (score 0):

Today is 16th september 2014 and I still facing this problem.

I don't know why anyone else did not answer about to comment GameHelper line. 
In onStop method there is a line to set mActivity variable as null.

I commented this line (like below) and my app is working properly.

```
  /** Call this method from your Activity's onStop(). */
public void onStop() {
    debugLog("onStop");
    assertConfigured("onStop");
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        debugLog("Disconnecting client due to onStop");
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    } else {
        debugLog("Client already disconnected when we got onStop.");
    }
    mConnecting = false;
    mExpectingResolution = false;



    // let go of the Activity reference
    //mActivity = null;  //COMMENT THIS LINE!!!!
    //COMMENT ABOVE LINE
}
```

Is there any problem doing that:?

Comment: Comment mActivity=null line. Like my explanation above.