# How can I make the Play Game Services not automatically sign in at the startup?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

Google provides the `BaseGameUtils` library, and [recommend us to extends its `BaseGameActivity`](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init). However, this class makes the game automatically sign in whenever the game is started. If the player does not want to or cannot connect to his Google account, this can be **very time consuming** at the beginning of the game.

So I dont' want this feature. Instead, I want to provide a sign in button. The player is connected only when he click that button. *And from that point on, every time the player starts the game, he is automatically connected to his Google account without clicking any button*. How can I do this?

Comment: haven't you seen [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018987/gamehelper-crashes-on-onconnectionfailed) error recently from the new version of the Google Play Services api? if you know some plz give some comment on it..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

OK, I have figured it out, **by default, the maximum auto sign-in times is 3**, which means if the user cancels 3 times, then the app will never again (unless you clear the app's data) automatically sign in. It's stored in `GameHelper.java`

```
 // Should we start the flow to sign the user in automatically on startup? If so, up to
 // how many times in the life of the application?
 static final int DEFAULT_MAX_SIGN_IN_ATTEMPTS = 3;
 int mMaxAutoSignInAttempts = DEFAULT_MAX_SIGN_IN_ATTEMPTS;
```

And it also provides a function to set this maximum number

```
public void setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(int max) {
        mMaxAutoSignInAttempts = max;
}
```

**So if you don't want any automatic signing-in attempt at all**, just call this function

This is if you don't want to extends BaseGameActivity

```
gameHelper = new GameHelper(this, GameHelper.CLIENT_GAMES);
gameHelper.enableDebugLog(true);
gameHelper.setup(this);
gameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
```

Or if you extends BaseGameActivity

```
getGameHelper().setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);
```

Comment: who on earth want it for 3 times? once is enough and twice is already annoying.. if I saw it 3 times on some app, i would think the APP DEVELOPER is a stupid from the hell.. even though it wasn't his design..

Comment: @tjPark I agree... I also had this issue and finding out that `DEFAULT_MAX_SIGN_IN_ATTEMPTS` was set to `3` was a real "wtf?!" moment for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer you provided. So if we set the max to 0, will it sign him automatically in IF the user already sign in before? Basically does it achieve the second part of the question and what do you set mConnectOnStart to?

Comment: I have found with players who don't have google play services installed on their phone, mainly foreign players or players with non-samsung phones, users are not getting past the signin process at all. It would be nice if samsung phones allowed you to disable, stop or uninstall google play services for testing, these options are grayed out or unavailable on my devices

Answer (score 10):

In the `GameHelper.java` file there is a boolean attribute called `mConnectOnStart` that by default it is set to true. Just change it to `false` instead:

```
boolean mConnectOnStart = false;
```

Additionally, there is a method provided for managing this attribute from the outside of the class:

```
// Not recommended for general use. This method forces the "connect on start"
// flag to a given state. This may be useful when using GameHelper in a 
// non-standard sign-in flow.
public void setConnectOnStart(boolean connectOnStart) {
    debugLog("Forcing mConnectOnStart=" + connectOnStart);
    mConnectOnStart = connectOnStart;
}
```

You can use the method above in order to customize your sign in process.
In my case, similar to you, I don't want to auto connect the very first time. But if the user was signed in before, I do want to auto connect. To make this possible, I changed the `getGameHelper()` method that is located in the `BaseGameActivity` class to this:

```
public GameHelper getGameHelper() {
    if (mHelper == null) {
        mHelper = new GameHelper(this, mRequestedClients);
        mHelper.enableDebugLog(mDebugLog);

        googlePlaySharedPref = getSharedPreferences("GOOGLE_PLAY",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean wasSignedIn = googlePlaySharedPref.getBoolean("WAS_SIGNED_IN", false);
        mHelper.setConnectOnStart(wasSignedIn);
    }
    return mHelper;
}
```

Every time, `getGameHelper()` method is called from `onStart()` in `BaseGameActivity`. In the code above, I just added the shared preference to keep if the user was signed in before. And called the `setConnectOnStart()` method according to that case.

Finally, don't forget to set the `"WAS_SIGNED_IN"` (or something else if you defined with different name) shared preference to true after user initiated sign in process.  You can do this in the `onSignInSucceeded()` method in the `BaseGameActivity` class.

Hope this will help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this, I don't know if this is the best way to do it. I changed the GameHelper class so it stores the user preference in the Shared Preferences:

```
...
public class GameHelper implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    ....

    // Whether to automatically try to sign in on onStart(). We only set this
    // to true when the sign-in process fails or the user explicitly signs out.
    // We set it back to false when the user initiates the sign in process.
    boolean mConnectOnStart = false;

    ...    

    /** Call this method from your Activity's onStart(). */
    public void onStart(Activity act) {
        mActivity = act;
        mAppContext = act.getApplicationContext();

        debugLog("onStart");
        assertConfigured("onStart");
        SharedPreferences sp = mAppContext.getSharedPreferences(GAMEHELPER_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mConnectOnStart = sp.getBoolean(KEY_AUTO_SIGN_IN, false);
        if (mConnectOnStart) {

        ...
    }

    ... 

    /** Sign out and disconnect from the APIs. */
    public void signOut() {

        ...

        // Ready to disconnect
        debugLog("Disconnecting client.");
        mConnectOnStart = false;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mAppContext.getSharedPreferences(GAMEHELPER_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_AUTO_SIGN_IN, false);
        editor.commit();
        mConnecting = false;
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    ...

    /**
     * Starts a user-initiated sign-in flow. This should be called when the user
     * clicks on a "Sign In" button. As a result, authentication/consent dialogs
     * may show up. At the end of the process, the GameHelperListener's
     * onSignInSucceeded() or onSignInFailed() methods will be called.
     */
    public void beginUserInitiatedSignIn() {
        debugLog("beginUserInitiatedSignIn: resetting attempt count.");
        resetSignInCancellations();
        mSignInCancelled = false;
        mConnectOnStart = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mAppContext.getSharedPreferences(GAMEHELPER_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putBoolean(KEY_AUTO_SIGN_IN, true);
        editor.commit();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

        ...
    }

    ...

    private final String GAMEHELPER_SHARED_PREFS = "GAMEHELPER_SHARED_PREFS";
    private final String KEY_SIGN_IN_CANCELLATIONS = "KEY_SIGN_IN_CANCELLATIONS";
    private final String KEY_AUTO_SIGN_IN = "KEY_AUTO_SIGN_IN";

    ...

}
```

See https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/FAQ.txt line 54 why you sign in automatically

Answer (score 1):

Call `getGameHelper().setConnectOnStart(false);` from onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the code from Google works exactly like you are talking about in the second paragraph.

> I want to provide a sign in button. The player is connected only when he click that button. And from that point on, every time the player starts the game, he is automatically connected to his Google account without clicking any button. How can I do this?

1. The Helper.setup method creates the clients
2. onStart looks at an internal boolean for auto-sign-in.  If the user was previously connected (and user did not sign out, or there was no error in disconnecting) then it will try to re-establish sign in.
3. beginUserInitiatedSignIn will set the auto-sign-in boolean if a successful connection is initiated
4. onStop will only terminate the connections gracefully, it does not reset the boolean

So the only way that the user sees the sign in process when your app starts, is if beginUserInitiatedSignIn is somehow called before pushing a button.

Make sure your beginUserInitiatedSignIn is not in your onStart method, nor is it called except by any other means than when your sign-in button is clicked and the User is NOT signed in.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    mHelper = new GameHelper(this);
    if (mDebugLog) {
        mHelper.enableDebugLog(mDebugLog, mDebugTag);
    }
    mHelper.setup(this, mRequestedClients, mAdditionalScopes);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mHelper.onStart(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHelper.onStop();
}


protected void beginUserInitiatedSignIn() {
    mHelper.beginUserInitiatedSignIn();
}
```

From the BaseGameUtil class

> /**
>    * Example base class for games. This implementation takes care of setting up
>    * the GamesClient object and managing its lifecycle. Subclasses only need to
>    * override the @link{#onSignInSucceeded} and @link{#onSignInFailed} abstract
>    * methods. To initiate the sign-in flow when the user clicks the sign-in
>    * button, subclasses should call @link{#beginUserInitiatedSignIn}. By default,
>    * this class only instantiates the GamesClient object. If the PlusClient or
>    * AppStateClient objects are also wanted, call the BaseGameActivity(int)
>    * constructor and specify the requested clients. For example, to request
>    * PlusClient and GamesClient, use BaseGameActivity(CLIENT_GAMES | CLIENT_PLUS).
>    * To request all available clients, use BaseGameActivity(CLIENT_ALL).
>    * Alternatively, you can also specify the requested clients via
>    * @link{#setRequestedClients}, but you must do so before @link{#onCreate}
>    * gets called, otherwise the call will have no effect.
>    *
>    * @author Bruno Oliveira (Google)

Comment: I think `onStart`, or `setup()` manages the automatically sign in process for us (implicitly calls `beginUserInitiatedSignIn()`). Anyway, I have figured out how to disable this process, see my answer

Comment: Actually, if the code from Google did exactly what he said in the second paragraph, this question would not have existed.

Comment: In the initial releases of the helper lib it was manual by default. Now it seems to be automatic by default.