# Is it possible to disable Google Play Services automatic sign in upon start up?

Tags: android

I have incorporated the newer google play game services into my app, and I can see that upon start up of my app, there is an automatic sign in. I was wondering if this could be disabled as I would like to give that option to the user. I have searched the code provided by BaseGameUtils, but I cant see any sign in functions being called anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [this issue](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/issues/49), auto sign on is the recommended pattern as stated in their [best practices video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QrXtqDzUPKk&t=3m18s). As they point out in the [FAQ](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-samples/blob/master/FAQ.txt) (questions 4 and 5):

> [4] Why is GameHelper/BaseGameActivity attempting to sign in on 
>   application startup?
>
> The default behavior of BaseGameActivity and GameHelper is to show the user
>       the sign-in flow (consent dialogs, etc) as soon as your application starts.
>       Naturally, once the user signs in for the first time, they won't see the
>       consent flow again, so it will be a seamless experience. It is important
>       for the user to sign in as early as possible so your application can take
>       advantage of the Google Play Games API right away (for example, saving the
>       user's progress using Cloud Save, unlocking achievements, etc). If the user
>       cancels the sign-in flow, BaseGameAcitivity/GameHelper will remember that
>       cancellation. If the total number of cancellations reaches a predefined
>       maximum (by default, 3), the user will no longer be prompted to sign in on
>       application startup. If that happens, they can still sign in by clicking
>       your application's Sign In button, if you provide one.
>
> [5] I don't like the new "auto sign in" feature of GameHelper. How can
>   I disable it?
>
> To disable this feature and return to the old behavior, you can edit
>       GameHelper.java and set the DEFAULT_MAX_SIGN_IN_ATTEMPTS constant to 0, or
>       call GameHelper.setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0) at runtime, before calling
>       GameHelper.setup() (or, correspondingly, from your Activity's onCreate
>       method).

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't even know this video existed. I just accidentally updated with my SDK Manager and it destroyed everything - I didn't even realise there was an update to google play games, so I have been rewriting my achievenemt/leaderboard logic. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I know it is an old question, but I was searching for an answer and I couldn't find easily (Thanks Google). This question pops up the first, so from another question, the answer is to use `getGameHelper().setMaxAutoSignInAttempts(0);`. As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22057683/1932105).