# Null Pointer Exception in Google Game Center

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, google-play-services

I am trying to incorporate Google Game Center but I am seeing this error which is force closing the app.
Here is the error

```
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    
at com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.GameHelper.resolveConnectionResult(GameHelper.java:856)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.GameHelper.onConnectionFailed(GameHelper.java:832)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ei.a(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.dy(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b.d(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.b$4.onConnectionFailed(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ei.a(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.b(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$h.a(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$b.ec(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.google.android.gms.internal.eh$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-31 18:35:12.822: E/AndroidRuntime(12814):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me solving this issue I am stuck on it very badly.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue accrues when the `mActivity == null`. There is [a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22018987/gamehelper-crashes-on-onconnectionfailed) about a similar issue which basically says that the function was called after the activity's `onStop()` method which nullifies `mActivity`.

This issue will probably be resolved soon so you should keep track of BaseGameUtils updates. As of April 8th 2014 of BaseGameUtils & Google Play Services v16 (4.3), this issue acuring.

The following patch fixes this issue - `GameHelper.java, line 849`, replace:

```
if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
```

with:

```
if ((mConnectionResult.hasResolution())&&(mActivity != null)) {
```